# InstancePerLifeTimeScope and the life time of the objects

Tags: autofac

I am very new to Autofac dependency injection and I got these questions related to my project. I have gone through many articles but I am not getting a clear picture on some of the questions I have. Mine is a service application on .Net REST API. I am doing instance registration in `App_Start` module as shown below.

```
private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterType<DCLMessengerContext>()
                   .As<DbContext>()
                   .ExternallyOwned()
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>()
                   .As<IDbFactory>()
                   .ExternallyOwned()
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
                   .As<IUnitOfWork>()
                  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityBaseRepository<>))
                   .As(typeof(IEntityBaseRepository<>))
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<PersonServiceClient>()
                   .As<IPerfService>()
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<PagingServiceContractClient>()
                   .As<PagingServiceContract>()
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<MessageService>()
                    .As<IMessageService>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            Container = builder.Build();
            return Container;

        }
```

My service layer is "MessageService" and there I am performing all the DB and other integration operations and getting the instances through constructor injection. These are the questions I have around this implementation.

1. I am using `InstancePerLifeTimeScope` for all my registrations. Is this is the right approach? After the life cycle of each controller request (http request), will these instances will be automatically disposed?
2. Do we need to manually implement any `Dispose` operation on any of these instances? ( I don’t have any unmanaged objects in my code)
3. From the service method, I need to create a fire&forget thread as well using `Task.Run()`. What is the best approach to supply instances to this fire&forget thread? If I use `InstancePerLifeTimeScope`, I can see that new thread also getting the same instances that available through the service class so I am just confused when these instances will be disposed?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thanks for updating this. I hope I can update the tilte as "InstancePerLifeTimeScope in Autofac and the life time of the objects". Also I hope there won't be any issue in adding additional tags (not with the title), in this case "ASP.Net Web API"?

Comment: that would make one perfect edit!

Comment: If you haven't already, you should probably [check out the documentation on lifetime scopes](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/index.html) since it addresses how scopes relate to disposal of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you resolve the instance per lifetime scope component, you get a
>   single instance per nested scope

1. So if you are using them in controllers. You will have one object for per request and they will be disposed. But if you resolve them in a singleton object they wil live with this object.

> Is this is the right approach?

It depends what you need. If you need singleton object, it's not. If you just want to use this service in request scope use instanceperrequest it's better.

2. Autofac automatically calls dispose for IDisposable objects. If you
   need dispose method, implement it. It's not related with autofac.
3. If you use another thread resolve objects in this thread. Otherwise when request disposed your objects will be disposed and your thread will be fail. Check [this](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#thread-scope).

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback
In my case as I mentioned, I am declaring all my objects as 'InstancePerLifeTimeScope'. Based on my understanding, the objects will be available throughout the lifetime of the request (http service call). When I am implementing Dispose() on some of these instances, I can see that Autofac framework is automatically calling dispose and disposing them. (due to char limit, splitting my comments)

Comment: 1. My question is if I am not implementing dispose interface on these classes, are these instances are going to stay in memory and this objects can cause the memory leakage on the app and eventually the app will die? Means, this objects are never going to clean up until we go for an app pool recycle?

Comment: 2. If the above statement is true and it is recommended to implement Dispose on all the instances, here in my case I have to implement Dispose on all the objects that I register with Autofac? Also I have many classes which I am creating internally through this Autofac registered classes, do we need to implement Dispose on all those objects as well? In short, If we are using Autofac registration or internally creating any instance (new keyword directly)?

Comment: If you have **unmanaged resources** you should write **dispose** method even if you are using autofac or not. If you don't have unmanaged reseorces, you don't need write dispose. They will not stay memory (until garabage collector collect them).

Comment: Even I had the same impression until I go through this article - http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/ . Kindly check this, "When an instance of MyResource is created in an Autofac container, the container will hold a reference to it even when it is no longer being used by the rest of the program. This means that the garbage collector will be unable to reclaim the memory held by that component, so the following program will eventually exhaust all available memory and crash:"

Comment: Yes it's true. If you want to resolve something by manual you should not resolve directly from container you should begin new lifetime scope. But  `builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`. So every request container begins new lifetimescope.

Comment: That's great to know! So in the case of a web api request, we are getting a new lifetime scope for each request so all the instances that we are registering in webapi.config will automatically taken care by the GC after the life time of the request( All managed resources)? Also, another concern I have is, I am starting a Fire&Forget thread (using Thread.Run(). If I am not implementing Dispose on my instances and with instanceperlifetime scope, I am getting the same instances and I can use them with the disconnected thread as well.  Do you think this approach is OK or do I need any change here?